# iOS - UIButton event crash

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsarray

I tried the codes of Moshe in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656432/create-a-for-loop-to-add-39-buttons-to-an-array), and it worked except the part of "for (UIButton *button in ..." and it crashes every time when I click on a button.

So I tried this code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,50,30,30)];
    testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [testButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commonMethodForButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [self.view addSubview:testButton];
    [testButton release];
```

My project contains nothing than this and Moshe´s sample codes. Any idea why the app crashes? I get no crash log.

EDIT:

in the open scope I have this method:

```
-(void)commonMethodForButtons:(id)sender
{
    NSLog (@"you touched me!");
}
```

EDIT 2:

I found the reason to this problem:

I commented out `[mvc release];` in AppDelegate, so it works perfectly now :)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MVC *mcv = [[MVC alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self.window addSubview: mcv.view];

    //[mcv release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Thank you for pointing this out! :)

Comment: do you have commonMethodForButtons: method implemented?

Comment: @vladimir I have added the code in the edit. this method was there before you asked.

Comment: try to set exception breakpoint or check console for error messages may be... your code looks fine so far.

Comment: What is your current class? is it view controller?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Is the `commonMethodForButtons:` implemented in your ViewController?

Comment: are u sure there is no typo issue in the name of the method? - usually the crash occurs when you the method you mentioned in the selector can't be found...

Comment: @vladimir It is UIViewController, yes.

Comment: @adam yes the method is implemented in the .h file. Like Moshe`s sample code.

Comment: @tiguero I have double-checked it now, so it is no typo. :/

Comment: @wagashi Methods should be implemented in `.m`. You can declare it in `.h`, but in this case there is no need for that.

Comment: Does anything retain this view controller that handles the button touch?

Comment: @wagashi are u using ARC? If yes remove the release method

Comment: @tiguero It wouldn't compile under ARC.

Comment: @adam I just followed Moshe´s sample codes. Ok, I see.

Comment: @philip please see my edit 2 :)

Comment: @tiguero what is ARC? anyway, please read my edit 2 :)

Comment: @wagashi That makes sense but you now technically have a leak because once that method is finished you have no way of releasing `mcv`.  In this case, it may not matter but it's good to get into the habit of accessing things as properties that you need to use later.

Comment: ARC stands for auto reference counting. Basically it tells your compiler where to add automatically the retain and release method so you don't have to worry about this. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368600/some-questions-about-automatic-reference-counting-in-ios5-sdk

Comment: @philip I see. How do I make mcv as a property?

Comment: @tiguero Ah, right, I have read about this before. No, I do not have ARC in this project.

Comment: In Xcode go to Product > Analyze and you probably will have a leak before the line you commented out

Comment: @Teofilo you are right, but how do I solve this? Philip mentioned that I should make mcv a property...but I don`t know how.

Comment: In the header file of the AppDelegate:

@ interface AppDelegate : UIResponder {
    MVC *mcv;
}

@ property (strong, nonatomic) MVC *mcv;

In the implementation file

@implementation AppDelegate

@ synthesize mcv;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [mcv release];
    [super dealloc];
}

Comment: Sorry, replace "strong" by "retain"

Comment: @teofile thanks. Could you post your own post, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: -1 You should not rely on your not releasing of the controller in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. If you ever converted to ARC (which you should) this would crash again. You should (a) not be adding mcv.view as a subview, but rather (b) set `self.window.rootViewController = mcv` and restore your `release` statement that you commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mcv as property

In the header file of the AppDelegate:

```
@class MVC;
    @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder {
    MVC *mcv;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MVC *mcv;
```

In the implementation file

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize mcv;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [mcv release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Um, I get warning in the header file: `error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MVC'` I have @interface xxxAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> { ...

Comment: @teofile I found the solution. Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428706/error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-xxx I get this warning because it is cyclical dependencies. I added `@class MVC;` in front of `@interface AppDelegate ...` in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should *not* be solving your problem by commenting out the `[mcv release]` (which is only fixing a symptom, not the problem, and will cause problems if you ever convert to ARC, which you should) nor should you, as in the currently accepted answer, be storing `mcv` (shouldn't that be `mvc`?) as an ivar of the app delegate but (a) failing to set `rootViewController` but (b) still using `addSubview`. You should use the app delegate's `rootViewController`. The current solutions will not configure your view controller hierarchy correctly. It should be as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MVC *mvc = [[MVC alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // really no NIB name?!?

    //[self.window addSubview: mvc.view];
    self.window.rootViewController = mvc;

    [mvc release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Or, better, conform to the standard `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` generated by the non-ARC Xcode templates, e.g.:

```
//  AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

And

```
//  AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "MVC.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[MVC alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // really no NIB name?!?
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I've never had to refer to this `viewController` property, but given that this is the default code that Xcode generates, I assume it is good practice.